# Override the browser shortcuts by my own custom shortcuts

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-shortcuts

I created one Asp.net MVC4 web application using C# which we can dynamically create keyboard shortcuts for all the pages.And we can use that keyboard shortcuts instantly to go to specific page.And the problem is every browser have their own default shortcuts.For example

If I create the keyboard shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> it should redirect to my own custom page. But the default browser shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> selects all from the page instead.

I want to disable the default browser shortcuts to give priority to my own custom shortcuts.Is this any way to achieve these? For my custom shortcuts,i used jquery keyUp event.I searched on internet,there suggestion are on jquery keyUp event,use preventDefault().But for accessing my own custom shortcuts,i am using keyUp event.So tell me suggestions to disable default browser shortcuts in all browsers either by C#, jquery or any other way.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not possible, at the very least it won't work reliably accross all browsers. You can listen to key events using `keydown` and check the event to see if CTRL was pressed, but the browser chrome will override any shortcuts you make in JS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will let you do this:

```
e.ctrlKey && String.fromCharCode(kc).toUpperCase()
```

checks for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to be pressed.

```js
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
  var kc = e.which || e.keyCode;

  if (e.ctrlKey && String.fromCharCode(kc).toUpperCase() == "A") {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(String.fromCharCode(kc).toUpperCase());
    window.location.href = 'your url here';
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
adfasfasdfsda
```

<sub>*You should click in the document to focus and then you can test it*.</sub>

Comment: If Ctrl + F1 is my shortcut key.but in IE default it is opening new IE browser.I tried this code but still no use.

Comment: Your answer is useful to achieve the shortcut keys like ctrl+A,ctrl+P...but coming to ctrl+ F1 to F12  or alt+F1 to F12 or shift +F1 to F12,I cant able to achieve that things.

Answer (score -1):

You had the procedure correct. I guess you can use ascii values to manipulate such things for eg: I use this for pressing enter key.

```
$('body').on('keypress', '#Selector-Id', function(e) {
if (e.which == 13) {
alert("Hi");
}
});
```

Comment: Just find the ascii codes for control and a and give those values instead of 13 (which is enter button ascii code) and it well help it out i guess!